# Outlook VBA Code to iterate through subfolder not working

Tags: vba, outlook

I got this code block from the internet but can't get it to work, if I comment out the line with `Folders("Temp")` it works fine.
Any ideas?
Thanks

```
Sub getmail2()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.mailitem

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Temp")

For Each msg In olFolder.Items
    Debug.Print msg.Subject
Next
End Sub
```

Does not iterate thru the `For Each` loop

Comment: Well, if the folder named Temp does not exist as a child of the Inbox folder, that line will generate a error. Do you actually need that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub getmail2()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim msg As Object ' You can use Object instead of Outlook.MailItem.

    ' Start the Outlook application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    ' Get the MAPI namespace
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Get the folder named "Temp"
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Temp")
    
    ' Process each email in the folder
    For Each msg In olFolder.Items
        If TypeOf msg Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Debug.Print msg.Subject
        End If
    Next

    ' Release objects
    Set msg = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man but it still doesn't iterate the For each loop, I'm thinking both set of codes is solid and that it's something else?
Maybe the references or something got screwed up, I dunno

Comment: The reason the loop is not working may be that you haven't correctly obtained the email items in a specific folder. Make sure the folder is correctly specified and that there are items in it.

Comment: Jeez, I feel like such and idiot, your nailed it, the folder/s I was testing were empty.Thanks!

Comment: I remember looking for a semicolon for an hour :)